# How to read data reference in a document firestore -flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an app with Firestore. I want to read the data of document A referenced from document B and get the fields I set in document B. I searched but can't seem to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Kindly show some code or explain it in detail. What attribute document has and on what basis (it's id or any attribute) you wanna fetch data.

Comment: I would shown code if I know how to

Comment: Doc A has fields in it stored as string data type. Doc B has a data type Ref, referencing to Doc A. What I want is get the fields stored in Doc A through Doc B.

Comment: You have to call  two services first to get the parameter. First call is to get the reference type and then call service again with orderBy filter on that reference  and limit to 1 to get only single record

Comment: Call two services, as in two streambuilder?

Comment: I have no experience of flutter . I know how to do it in android

Comment: Can you provide the code in java? I'll try to follow the algorithm and apply for flutter. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get ref_value like this

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('collection')
    .where('ref', isEqualTo: 'what you want to query')
    .getDocuments()
    .then((doc) {
  ref_value = doc.documents[0]['ref'];
});
```

get another with that reference

```
await Firestore.instance
    .collection('collection')
    .where('ref', isEqualTo: ref_value)
    .limit(1)
    .getDocuments()
    .then((doc) {
  ref_value = doc.documents[0]['ref'];
});
```

this code may help you try out things further..